# understanding the smart pointer boost in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ as well as smart pointer.
I have a code like this.

```
Example* Example::get_instance() {
        Example* example = new Example();
        return example;
}
```

I am trying to convert it to smart pointer like this

```
shared_ptr<Example> Example::get_instance() {
        shared_ptr<Example> example (new Example());
        return example;
}
```

Is this the correct way because when i am trying to call this from another class its not working.I am trying to implement a singleton object.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: What is not working? And that is definitely not the way to create a singleton. Every call to `get_instance` will create a new instance of your *singleton*.

Comment: yes i understand that . What i am asking is can i return an shared pointer like this?shared_ptr<Example> Example::get_instance()  or do it need to do like this Example* Example::get_instance() {

Comment: @Kathick What you've posted will compile, but it's not creating a singleton. Only you can answer whether that'll work for you or not. Also, prefer using `std::make_shared` (or `boost::make_shared`) to create `shared_ptr` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `Example` object every time the object is requested, That is a memory leak, an you are also returning a different object every time. Try this instead:

```
Example & Example::get_instance() {
        static Example example;
        return example;
}
```

Also please note the following advices for your code:

- when creating smart pointers prefer `make_shared` instead of `shared_ptr<YourType>(new YourType(...))`. The reason why can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Relevant excerpt:

  > This function typically allocates memory for the T object and for the
  >   shared_ptr's control block with a single memory allocation (it is a
  >   non-binding requirement in the Standard). In contrast, the declaration
  >   std::shared_ptr p(new T(Args...)) performs at least two memory
  >   allocations, which may incur unnecessary overhead. Moreover,
  >   f(shared_ptr(new int(42)), g()) can lead to memory leak if g
  >   throws an exception. This problem doesn't exist if make_shared is
  >   used.
- understand the difference between [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). For your case, a `std::unique_ptr` would have been better, but there is an even simpler solution to your problem, which I have shown above.
- in general, avoid pointers when you can use references instead, they're easier to use and code looks a bit cleaner.
- and finally, do you REALLY want a singleton? I just have to be ask. I've been working full-time as a programmer for almost 4 years now. Not that long, I know, but enough to have encountered the situation where I regretted that I or someone else used the Singleton pattern instead of passing the reference to my object down the call chain.

Try to avoid singletons, you may later find your code using the singleton might in the end want to work on multiple instances of your `Example` object instead of calling Example::get_instance and only work on that single instances. So when you'll have that revelation, (and it might be only a matter of time), you'll have major refactoring ahead of you.

So, "Beware, there be dragons!".

Comment: Or forget about the boolean and the smart pointer, create a static instance of the object within the function and return a reference (or pointer) to it. There's no need to involve smart pointers when trying to implement a singleton.

Comment: true, true :)) Worked on OPs code and couldn't see the forest from the trees.

Comment: @Zadirion may i know why you said "make_shared instead of shared_ptr"